# iAd Autolayout Issue after click

Tags: ios6, iad, autolayout

I have some layout problem when i **clic** on "Test advertiser" iAd Banner :

[image: Ad Clicked]

[image: View after clic]

I don't understand because **everything is well** displayed before i clic on the banner.

[image: View before clic]

**I'm using auto layout.**

Here's my view hierarchy
UIView
|
ContentView
    |NavigationBar
    |Tableview
|BannerView

I keep a reference from contentView bottom constraint and bannerView bottom constraint

Here's my code :

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        _eventsController = [[EventsController alloc]init];
        if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"showADs"])
        {
            NSLog(@"Show ADs");
            _bannerView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithAdType:ADAdTypeBanner];
            [self.bannerView setDelegate:self];
        }
    }
    return self;
}
```

**ViewDidAppear**

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
    {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    NSLog(@"viewDidAppear");
    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"showADs"])
    {
        [self.view addSubview:self.bannerView];
        [self.bannerView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

        [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.bannerView
                                                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                                             relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                toItem:self.contentView
                                                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                                             multiplier:1.0 constant:0]];

        self.bannerviewBottomConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.bannerView
                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                     relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                        toItem:self.contentView
                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                    multiplier:1.0 constant:50];
        [self.view addConstraint:self.bannerviewBottomConstraint];
        [self.view setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
        [self.view setNeedsLayout];
    }
}
```

**AdBannerViewDelegate**

```
#pragma mark - ADBannerView Delegate
- (void)updateLayoutForAD
{
    if (self.bannerView.bannerLoaded)
    {
        self.contentViewBottomConstraint.constant = -50.0;
        self.bannerviewBottomConstraint.constant = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        self.contentViewBottomConstraint.constant = 0;
        self.bannerviewBottomConstraint.constant = 50;
    }

    [self.view setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    }];
}

- (void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner
{
    NSLog(@"GOT AD");    
    [self updateLayoutForAD];
}

- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"DIDN'T GOT AD");
    [self updateLayoutForAD];
}
```